# Enabale auto-complete for Laravel 4 in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to add auto-complete with documentation for Laravel 4 in Netbeans. 
I try to search and found this code(https://github.com/ethaizone/laravel-netbeans-autocompletion). Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Laravel 4.

Anyone have any idea or solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper.
It use artisan command to generate ide helper file

Answer (score 2):

Just download this file [_ide_helper.php](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822) and put it in the root directory of your project

Comment: The best answer by far. Been trying different ways for days. This worked perfectly. Thanks a millions :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder inside programfiles/netbeans/php then I saved the file which u can grab from following url. I updated the PHP global include path to above folder from Netbeans. Next time when you create a Laravel you don't need to set the include file path. Netbeans will support Laravel code completion.

[download the file from this page](http://raroweb.net/projects/webdev_helper/netbeans/laravel-4-in-eclipse-or-netbeans/)